# Problems with showing image from blob, php file

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I am new to PHP and I have problems showing images from the database. There are a lot of article and posts about that, but nothing worked for me.

The images are saved correctly in database, I can see that

Here is my code:

**saveimage.php**

```
function uploadImage($name, $image, $type) {
    require 'db_config.php';
    /* @var $DBH PDO */
    try {
        $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO images (name,image,type) VALUES (:name ,:image,:type)");
        $STH->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $STH->bindParam(':image', $image);
        $STH->bindParam(':type', $type);
        $STH->execute();

        $DBH = null;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "Error: " . $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**showimage.php**

```
require 'db_config.php';
/* @var $DBH PDO */

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    try {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT name,image,type FROM images WHERE id=" . $id);
        $STH->execute();

        $image = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $DBH = null;

        header("Content-Type: " . $image->type);
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($image->name));
        echo $image->image;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "Error: " . $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**index.php:**

```
<div>
        <img src="showimage.php?id=5" width="200" height="200">
</div>
```

Comment: you need to show us more code than that. we can tell that you are passing data to showimage.php but the code you show doesn't have any use of `$_GET` variables or the query of where the id is being used

Comment: Content length would be the size of the blob, I'm pretty sure `filesize($image->name)` is going to fail.